Let $A$ be a countable set and suppose there is a function mapping $A$ onto $B$. Prove $B$ is countable.
I was working on an exercise from Kaplansky's Set Theory and Metric Spaces about countable sets. The problem states: Let $A$ be a countable set and suppose there is a surjective function mapping $A$ onto $B$. Prove that $B$ is countable.
I came across a proof regarding the countability of sets and would really appreciate some help understanding it better.
https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/Courses/MAU22200/MAU22200_Hil2020_Slides/MAU22200_Hil2020_Countability_Slides.pdf
Although this is not my proof, I hope it's okay to share my summary here. The outline of the proof is as follows:

The set $A$ is countable so there exists a injective function $g: A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists (at most one) $a \in A$ such that $g(a) = n$.

Denote the surjective function $h: A \rightarrow B$. Then for every $b \in B$ there is (at least one) $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

If we combine (1) and (2) we get that for any $b \in B$ there exists at least one $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (that satisfies n = g(a) for some $a\in A$) satisfying $n = h(a)$.

For every $b \in B$. Let $f(b)$ be the smallest $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that satisfies $n = g(a)$ for some $a \in A$ (that also satisfies $h(a) = b$).

If we can prove that $f$ is injective we have proved that an injective map exists between $B$ and $\mathbb{N}$ and therefore $B$ is countable.

If we let $b_1, b_2 \in B$ and $b_1 \neq b_2$. Then we have $a_1, a_2 \in A$ such that the following is satisfied:

$f(b_1) = g(a_1)$
$f(b_2) = g(a_2)$
$b_1 = h(a_1)$
$b_2 = h(a_2)$


In the proof I linked to above, it is stated that since $b_1 \neq b_2$, we have $a_1 \neq a_2$. I am having trouble understanding how to conclude this given that $g$ is injective and $h$ is surjective. Can someone help clarify this step?

If $a_1 \neq a_2$ holds. We have that $g(a_1) \neq g(a_2)$ since $g$ is injective, and therefore $f(b_1) \neq f(b_2)$. Since we have showed that $b_1 \neq b_2$ implies $f(b_1) \neq f(b_2)$, we can conclude that $f$ is injective.


So I need some help with going from step number 6 to step number 7. Please let me know if I have done something else wrong, and I will try to correct it.

Let $A={a_i}{i\in\mathbb N}$. For all $b\in B$, there is $i_b$ s.t. $b=f(a{i_b})$. Since ${a_{i_b}}_{b\in B}\subset A$ is countable, then so is $B$.

Thank you! I get it now! Your proof was much more effective than what I was working with. Really appreciate your help!

Sorry to bother you again, but I just want to make sure that this is correct. We have ${a_{i_b}}{b \in B} \subset A$, and this proves that we have found a correspondence between all $b \in B$ and elements $a{i_b}$ in $A$. And this tells us that $B$ is countable if $A$ is countable. Right?

Do you have the theorem that $S$ is countable if and only if there is a surjective function $\Bbb N\to S$? That seens to me like a simpler way to go.

No, I don't have that theorem. But if I did, I could use the fact that $g \circ f$ is surjective if both $g$ and $f$ are surjective. If I choose $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ and $g: A \rightarrow B$, then I would have a function that is surjective from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow B$, which would prove that $B$ is countable, right?

Yes, exactly so.

@Mathstudent123 : You get that $B={f(a_{i_b})}{b\in B}$. Since ${a{i_b}}_{b\in B}\subset A$, you get that $B$ is countable as well since there are at most $|A|$ elements in $B$. All the key is the fact that $f$ is onto.

Ok, got it! Thank you!

It's not a matter of h being injective or not, it's just that h is a function and can't map 1 point to 2.To clarify, assume that a1 = a2 = a, then we have h(a1) = b1 = h(a), and h(a2) = b2 = h(a) therefore b1 = b2 = h(a) which contradict the fact that b1 != b2. Hope this helps.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

You can also write $f^{-1}(B)=A$ as $f$ is a surjection, this means $f^{-1}(B)$ is countable. But $|B|\le |f^{-1}(B)|$ because $f$ is a many-to-one relation, so $f^{-1}$ is one-to-many relation. This means $B$ is countable.
